# Safari extensions beforeNavigate event not triggers

Tags: javascript, browser, safari

When the user enters URL into the address bar and hit enter or clicks bookmark the 'beforeNavigate' event is not catched. But it works if open a link on a webpage.
Any idea how to get initial requested URL?
Sample code:

```
//global.html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<script>

safari.application.addEventListener("beforeNavigate", openHandler, true);

function openHandler(e) {
    console.log(e);
}
</script>
```

Comment: You can't have a `script` element immediately following the doctype. It must be within the `head` or `body` elements.

Comment: Nowadays the browser creates head and body automatically as web inspector shows. I took initial sample from Apple https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/samplecode/UnreadTabsSafariExtension/Listings/UnreadTabs_safariextension_global_html.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011114-UnreadTabs_safariextension_global_html-DontLinkElementID_4

Comment: Right. I forgot, it just bugs me...